# OpenVPN redirect-gateway no Internet access

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn, nat

i know this is asked like hundred times before, but i'm using as a VPN server a windows 10 machine.

so the problem is that i dont have Internet access when i include the push "redirect-gateway" on the config of the VPN server.
the reason why i include this command is, because i want all the traffic to redirect through the vpn tunnel, so when im searching whatsmyip, to get the NAT ip of the network that the server is installed.

**heres the config of the server :**

```
dev-node "serverVPN"
mode server
port xxxxxxxxxxxx

proto tcp4-server
dev tun

tls-server
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ta.key" 0

tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ServerVPN.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ServerVPN.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh4096.pem"

server 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
#push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"

client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun

client-config-dir "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config"

verb 3

route-delay 5
route-method exe

push "redirect-gateway def1"

push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0" #itan 0.0
route 192.168.182.0 255.255.255.0
```

**and heres the config file of the client:**

```
remote xxxxxxxxxxx
client
port xxxxx
proto tcp4-client
dev tun
tls-client
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1
remote-cert-tls server
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ClientVPN1.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ClientVPN1.key"

cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
redirect-gateway def1
verb 3
mute 20
```

i may need to make a NAT outbound in the router, but i have the one that my ISP gave me, and i cant configure NAT through the GUI of the router, but i do have access in the CLI through TELNET, the problem there is, that i dont know the commands to give, to make this

**heres how the CLI of the router lookes like its a technicolor MediaAccess TG788vn v2:**
[Login interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v093l.png)

[commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mWx2.png)

[NAT commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXyKN.png)

Comment: Have you configured IP routing (and NAT) _on the VPN server_? If the server doesn't perform NAT, then have you configured the router to know about the VPN subnet?

Comment: @grawity the problem with that is that there is no option in the GUI of my router, so i should do it from the CLI through telnet, where i dont know what command to give

Comment: @grawity i managed to get access by enabling network share in the ethernet adapter of the VPNserver. Is that correct way ?